# How can I merge one array with values into an array with stdClass objects?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two arrays and looking for the way to merge them. Standard `array_merge()` function don't work.

Do you know any nice solution without foreach iteration?

My first array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Green
            [count] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Yellow
            [count] => 
        )
)
```

My second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 7
)
```

And as a result I would like to get:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Green
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Yellow
            [count] => 7
        )
)
```

Comment: Please add your attempt(s) to your question.

Comment: I have tried array_merge function.

Comment: @user889349 Then add your attempt to your question and show your work/effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

  $first_array = array( 
            (object)array("field_value"=>"green","count"=>null),
            (object)array("field_value"=>"yellow","count"=>null)
             );

  $second_array = array(2,7);


  function simple_merge($arr1, $arr2)
  {
    return array_map(function($a,$b){ $a->count = $b; return $a; },$arr1,$arr2);
  }

  print_r($first_array);
  print_r($second_array);
  print_r(simple_merge($first_array,$second_array));

 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 Array
 (
     [0] => stdClass Object
         (
             [field_value] => green
             [count] => 
         )

     [1] => stdClass Object
         (
             [field_value] => yellow
             [count] => 
         )

 )
 Array
 (
     [0] => 2
     [1] => 7
 )
 Array
 (
     [0] => stdClass Object
         (
             [field_value] => green
             [count] => 2
         )

     [1] => stdClass Object
         (
             [field_value] => yellow
             [count] => 7
         )

 )
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

Just simply loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and pass the argument from array one as reference. Then you can simply assign the value to the count  property.

```
<?php

    array_map(function(&$v1, $v2){
        $v1->count = $v2;
    }, $arr1, $arr2);

    print_r($arr1);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Green
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_value] => Yellow
            [count] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: @user889349 You're welcome! (You still can add your attempts to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257588/php-array-merge-and-coutn/30257672?noredirect=1#comment48614966_30257588)

Comment: @user889349 May I know what is better in the accept answer than mine?

Answer (score 0):

it is simple

code:

```
 $i = 0;
    foreach($firstarrays as $firstarr)
    {
        $firstarr['count'] = $secondarray[$i];
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$a1 = Array(
    (object) Array('field_value' => 'Green', 'count' => null),
    (object) Array('field_value' => 'Yellow', 'count' => null)
);

$a2 = Array(2, 7);

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($a1); $i++) {
    $a1[$i]->count=$a2[$i];
}
```